# Example for $\mathbb{N} ^ \mathbb{N}$ linear order

Tags: order-theory

I'm not really sure if something like $ \{1,2,3,...\} < \{2,2,3,...\} < \{3,2,3,...\}$ works.

I don't ask about solution with transitive, antisymmetric and total proof, just for working example. Greetings!

**EDIT:**
Originally the topic was about total order but I had wanted to consider linear order. Sorry for that!

Comment: What is the difference between total and linear order?

Comment: Okay, now I see. I'm using few different sources of knowledge in two different languages. So can we put '=' between linear and total, alright?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexicographic order is a total order on $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  That is,
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)<(b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots)
$$
if and only if $a_j<b_j$ and $a_i=b_i$ for $i<j$ (which is vacuously true if $j=1$).

Answer (score 0):

Try lexicographic order. (This will be like alphabetical order, but the alphabet is $\mathbb{N}$ and every word is infinitely long.)